# how to get parent object in multi table inheritance in django

Tags: django, django-models, multi-table-inheritance

I have the following two models that use multi table inheritance.  PlayerAchievment extends OverallAchievment:

```
class OverallAchievment(models.Model):
    achievement = models.ForeignKey(Achievement)
    match = models.ForeignKey(Match, limit_choices_to={'week_number': 2})
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)


class PlayerAchievement(OverallAchievment):
    player = models.ForeignKey(Player)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.player.first_name + ' ' + self.player.last_name

    def match_detail(self):
        ??? how to get match info here?
```

I want pull some info about the match attribute of the parent in the PlayerAchievement child function.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `PlayerAchievement` extends from `OverallAchievment` you can use its attributes:

```
def match_detail(self):
    self.match.<attr_here>
    ...
```